# BluetoothUserSupport Service issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, services

I have a strange problem with Bluetooth on Windows 10. All the latest drivers and Windows updates are installed, services set to 'automatic' run. Bluetooth devices paired and and working well, but only after computer restart - never after the first boot.

When computer is off and I turn it on manually the BluetoothUserSupport Service in services.msc starts with its name in Polish, my OS languag - then Bluetooth doesn't work. After restart the same service shows up with English name and then everything works well, as it should.

Any ideas how to fix that problem, please?

I have already tried troubleshoot, system scan, different drivers etc.